# Flex mobile issue with Symantec App Center

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, intellij-idea, symantec

I'm compiling an app that needs to be uploaded to Symantec App Center, but can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I get [the following error](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH215403), but since I'm using Flex and IntelliJ to compile the app this error message does not mean anything to me.. I only have to set the certificate one place, not two. The app installs fine via iTunes and is working btw.

Anyone have a clue as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the app id, provisioning profile and distribution cert set correctly. To deploy it to the symatec app store you'll need to have an "In-House" provisioning profile.

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO83981